# SQL - unexpected change in number of results after adding left join

Tags: sql, left-join

The following query:

```
SELECT Assets.Id, Assets.Description
FROM Assets
WHERE CaseNumber = 1265
```

produces 29 results.

After adding the following left join onto another table:

```
SELECT Assets.Id, Assets.Description
FROM Assets
LEFT JOIN StockShares ON StockShares.AssetId = Assets.AssetId
WHERE CaseNumber = 1265
```

I'm down to 3. This has totally thrown me. I thought I knew about SQL?

Can anyone either confirm this result is not quite right, or explain why the number of results has dropped?

Comment: Yes - in fact, I have found that I can reproduce the result with just two tables (i.e. a single join). I have updated the SQL above in order to show that.

Comment: which sql product are you using?

Comment: why do you add a LEFT JOIN on StockShares table if you don't select any StockShares field?

Comment: Just for demonstration purposes. In reality, I would want columns from StockShares but I haven't continued writing the query because it's so obviously not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you've added to a query is a `LEFT JOIN` (with `ON` clause), then the number of results should *stay the same* or *increase* - if no rows match the join criteria, the result count should remain static. If there are multiple matching rows in the right table, for a single row in the left table, then the result count will increase.

If you add a `LEFT JOIN`, but also add new conditions into your `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses, you may effectively transform your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. In such a case, the number of results may obviously drop. What has to be borne in mind is that the entire `WHERE` clause (also, `HAVING`) must be true for a result to appear in the final result set. If you're referencing columns from the right side of a `LEFT JOIN`, then you must consider what will happen when such columns are `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that I can reproduce the same result with two tables and a single left join confirms to me that we have a problem with the platform's implementation of SQL (Interbase XE, if you're curious). I'm no SQL noob by the way, I was totally shocked to see this, hence my posting here to see if there was some nuance of SQL I'd missed all these years.

Comment: How come a left join gets converted to a inner join with where thats completely wrong. The fact that join has happened before where the reason the results decreased

Answer (score 2):

Replace WHERE with AND.

WHERE applies after the join; AND applies during the join.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible given the code you're showing.  Something else is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

If `AssetId` is `NULL` the join will fail to yield as many results. You can play with this sample fiddle here (code below): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/97124/2

```
CREATE TABLE Assets(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Description VARCHAR(200),
    AssetId INT
);

CREATE TABLE Stockshares(
  AssetId INT
);

insert into assets values('desription1', 1);
insert into assets values('desription2', null);
insert into assets values('desription3', null);

insert into Stockshares values(1);
insert into Stockshares values(2);
insert into Stockshares values(3);


Select * from assets
join stockshares on stockshares.assetid = assets.assetid
where stockshares.AssetId = 1 -- change to 2,  get less results because AssetId is null for asset 2
```

Here's some documentation for joining on nulls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017#nulls_joins

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the where clause before joining youll get the same results. The fact that where is applied after the left join has happened has filtered out most records as the left join on unmatched records would be null and hence reduced the record count

Comment: Look at the first query. It doesn't join. The question is not a case of changing from inner join to left join. Moreover, if an inner join were changed to outer join then the number of rows returned cannot decrease because the left join sends the same rows into the where as an inner join plus maybe more. This is explained in the answer by Damien_The_Unbeliever. Neither case is the sort of common error you are describing.